# Installshield Limited Edition - Entity Framework

Tags: deployment, installshield, publish

I have Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate, and am trying to create an installation package for a product of mine.

I have tried both Installshield Limited Edition for Visual Studio and I have downloaded the Visual Studio installer package.

With both, I am not sure how to add the Entity framework libraries as they are not picked up automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Managed it with Installshield Limited Edition for Visual Studio 2013.

Open the Project Assistant

Click on the "application files" icon at the bottom. Select the "Add Files" button in the lower right of the Project Assistant and go to the release folder within your project and add all the files. If you have directories, then these are simply added using the button to the right of the "Add Files" marked "Add Folders".

This compiled up OK and allowed me to install the C# DLL onto my target machine.